# What is the alternative to module: tf.keras.preprocessing?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, kaggle

I am using the following snippet for augmentation:

```
# Data augmentation
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    fill_mode='constant',
    cval = 0)
```

Additionally, I am using GPU P100 on Kaggle. I was having some errors when I would run the `model.fit` method. So I was debugging.

Only untill I went through the Keras doc, I knew that the Module: tf.keras.preprocessing is deprecated. Or at least this is what I understood from this doc [link.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing)

Also, hovering over the preprocessing header that encloses the overview, a small pop-up reads **Deprecated**.

[image: The image reference]

I wanted to know what is the alternative now?